# Flutter - Converting minutes into H:M

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, intl

I'm looking for a method to convert minutes into hours and minutes. I'm using the `intl` package through `DateFormat` but this requires both `hours` and `minutes` so it won't do.

If I have `100` minutes, I would like this to be converted to `01:40`. Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Does this work?

```
String durationToString(int minutes) {
    var d = Duration(minutes:minutes);
    List<String> parts = d.toString().split(':');
    return '${parts[0].padLeft(2, '0')}:${parts[1].padLeft(2, '0')}';
}

print(durationToString(100)); //returns 01:40
```

Comment: I need to be able to pass a variable to this and I can't change `d` to `int` from `Duration` as I'm getting `Only valid value is 0:1`

Comment: @Jake I updated it to be more in line with original ask.  Hope it helps, otherwise I might need more info to understand the question.

Answer (score 16):

This will work for you

```dart
String getTimeString(int value) {
  final int hour = value ~/ 60;
  final int minutes = value % 60;
  return '${hour.toString().padLeft(2, "0")}:${minutes.toString().padLeft(2, "0")}';
}
```

Comment: Posted this before I saw [socasanta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56918492/6891637)'s answer. It might be the better implementation

Comment: Never knew about ~ or .padLeft(). Thanks.