# Flutter - Convert minutes to TimeOfDay

Tags: flutter, dart, timeofday

Currently I get a number from the BE that states like `750` minutes (int) and should represent the time of day.

> 750 minutes = 12.5 hours and so the UI should display 12:30
>
> 1080 minutes = 18 hours and so the UI should display 18:00

But I can't seem to find a way to get a clean convertion from minutes to a proper Object with hours and minutes.

In the end I want to have a `TimeOfDay` object

I will continue to struggle and will also post if I find the answer myself :)

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918229/flutter-converting-minutes-into-hm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Converting minutes into H:M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918229/flutter-converting-minutes-into-hm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the comments above I resolved it by splitting the sting. I don't see this as the best way to convert since I'm dependened that the Duration Class will never change but never the less I got what I wanted by doing the following

```
  TimeOfDay minutesToTimeOfDay(int minutes) {
      Duration duration = Duration(minutes: minutes);
      List<String> parts = duration.toString().split(':');
      return TimeOfDay(hour: int.parse(parts[0]), minute: int.parse(parts[1]));
  }
```

Create `Duration` with the amount of minutes, then `toString()` that instance this will outpout `00:00` and then split this string on the colon ":"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing two mathematical operations like this:

```
  TimeOfDay minutesToTimeOfDay(int minutesPastMidnight) {
      int hours = minutesPastMidnight ~/ 60;
      int minutes = minutesPastMidnight % 60;
      return TimeOfDay(hour: hours, minute: minutes);
  }
```

This is roughly based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919555/10307728) to a related question.